# fastcall how to use for more than 4 parameters

Tags: c++, assembly, call, fasm, fastcall

I was trying to build a function in assebmly(FASM) that used more than 4 parameters. in x86 it works fine but I know in x64 with fastcall you have to spill the parameters into the shadow space in the order of rcx,rdx,r8,r9 I read that for 5 and etc you have to pass them onto the stack, but I don't know how to do this. this is what I tried but it keeps saying **invalid operand**. I know that the first 4 parameters I am doing right because I have made x64 functions before but it is the last 3 I don't know how to spill

```
proc substr,inputstring,outputstring,buffer1,buffer2,buffer3,startposition,length
;spill
mov [inputstring],rcx
mov [outputstring],rdx
mov [buffer1],r8
mov [buffer2],r9
mov [buffer3],[rsp+8*4]
mov [startposition],[rsp+8*5]
mov [length],[rsp+8*6]
```

if I try

```
mov [buffer3],rsp+8*4
```

it says extra characters on the line.
I also saw that somepeople use rsp+20h, rsp+28h etc but that does not work either.
how do I call more than 4 parameters using fastcall on x64?
also do I have to make room on the stack? I saw some people have to put add rsp,20h right before their spill code. I tried that and it did not help the invlaid operand.
thanks

**update**

after playing around with it for a little bit I found that the only way it seems to work is if I spill the first 4 parameters and then ignore the rest 5-infinity

```
proc substr,inputstring,outputstring,buffer1,buffer2,buffer3,startposition,length
;spill
mov [inputstring],rcx
mov [outputstring],rdx
mov [buffer1],r8
mov [buffer2],r9

;start the regular code. ignore spilling buffer3,startposition and length
```

Comment: you can't use mov to move from pointer to pointer, you need to load into register first.

Answer (score 0):

On x86/x64-CPUs this following instructions does not exist:

```
mov [buffer3],[rsp+8*4]
mov [startposition],[rsp+8*5]
mov [length],[rsp+8*6]
```

Workaround with using the rax-register for to read and for to write a values from and to a memory loaction:

```
mov rax,[rsp+8*4]
mov [buffer3],rax
mov rax,[rsp+8*5]
mov [startposition],rax
mov rax,[rsp+8*6]
mov [length],rax
```

Comment: I tried this before, but it does not work. it compiles but when I run the function it gives me an APPCRASH